# Chat Application Lobby ListView

Tags: android, android-listview

I've created a chat application **GCM** service and broadcast receivers and i have a Lobby which is a ListView. When user clicks plus button on the top right corner it launches a new chat window and when back button pressed it goes back to lobby creating a item that indicates active chat(just like whatsapp). My questions are:

1-) i can't use my list items properly. How should i populate the list when specific chat room has new message and brings up the notification on list item?

2-)how can i manage the broadcast data which comes from server into receiver. how am i supposed to know which chat room has new message?

Any tutorial is appreciated. I already read the AndroidIM project but its too wide for me to understand.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1-) i can't use my list items properly. How should i populate the list
>   when specific chat room has new message and brings up the notification
>   on list item?

You can update the data that used to populate your list and then use `adapter.notifyDatasetChanged();` method to make the ListView repaint its content.

> 2-)how can i manage the broadcast data which comes from server into
>   receiver. how am i supposed to know which chat room has new message?

Many approaches can be used here. You can use Local broadcast to re-direct the data to ListView screen from the GCM broadcast. Regarding the chatrooms you should create a same logic between server-client in order to identify them and make the server send the data of the updated chat.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but think i couldn't explained myself clearly. What i meant is when a message comes from server i can easily save it. But how am i supposed to update list view new message counter? I mean new message came but to which chat room. My adapter extends arrayadapter<string>. So what should i do to add specific item new message number(i know how to create custom adapter and implement it)

Comment: Is there another way for chatroom implementation? I mean not using server to send data of updated chat?

Comment: Just make your adapter keep more data and your server communication more smart to say WHICH chat should be updated.

I guess there are dozen ways of implementing a chat with many different protocols http, jabber, mqtt, sockets.